# Drools - centralize rules without centralizing the domain model

Tags: drools

We have set up a SOA with a few common framework pojos and a lot of service-specific pojos. I now want to set up drools brm, preferably with guvnor.
We cannot refactor the models to get one central domain model (and we dont really want to, since we try to keep inter-service-dependencies minimal).

Since I can model Fact-structures in drools directly, I started thinking if the common model is necessary at all ... what is your opinion/experience?

Answer (score 0):

Would creating a guvnor *package* (=module) of *assets* (=rules) per subset of all domain objects work? Each package (=module) has it's own deployment lifecycle.

Comment: The subsets of Domain models are service specific, hence my packages would be service specific. Would be only sligtly better than keeping the rules directly in the services ...